# How to post to a database from a form

Tags: php, laravel

How to post the contents of a form to db? I know the database works.

```
    <form method="post" action="{{ action('UserController@registration') }}">
         <h1>Please Name</h1>
         <textarea name="name"></textarea> 
        <button type="submit">Access</button>
    </form>

Route::post('/registration', 'UserController@registration');

public function registration(Request $request)
{
    DB::table(‘user2s’)->insert([‘name’=> $request->name]);
    return 'success';
}
```

Comment: What's the error that you are getting?

Comment: use eloquent models, anyway that should work if you did nothing else wrong

Comment: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php. I get the error even if the add to DB line is commented.

Comment: This works on the same page "         $user = DB::table('user2s')->where('name', $request->name)->first();
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this token in your form

```
{!! Form::token() !!}
```

or this

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />
```

Comment: I am super new at web and Laravel. How do I integrate it with the code?

Comment: <form method="post" action="{{ action('WelcomeController@save') }}">
   {!! Form::token() !!}
</form>

Comment: Thks, I had to install forms.

Comment: you can also add token using plain html withouth Laravel form. <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />